# How to calculate SD from pre SD and post SD?

Tags: variance

I have two values of SD calculated from paired samples of size $n=10$.

Results are:

1. Pre test - mean=29.1 and SD=19.05
2. Post test - mean=34.9 and SD=16.74

How do I calculate the SD?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the standard deviation of both samples combined?

Comment: If the pairings are pretest-posttest and you want to compute the SD of the test *differences* (which is what is relevant when you're interested in testing for a nonzero effect), then the answer is that you cannot get that answer from the data given.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're asking about the variance of the aggregate of two data sets. That is, if you have two data sets $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $Y = (Y_1, ..., Y_m)$, you want to determine the standard deviation of the aggregated data set, $Z = (X_1, ..., X_n, Y_1, ..., Y_m)$, given knowledge of the means and standard deviations of $X$ and $Y$.

It is a fact that the variance of an aggregated data set, $V$, is

$$ V = \left( {\rm variance\ of \ the \ averages} \right) + \left( {\rm average\ of\ the\ variances} \right) $$

This is a consequence of **[the law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)**. From the data you gave the variance of the averages is $8.41$ and the average of the variances is $321.565$. So, the standard deviation of the aggregate is approximately

$$ S = \sqrt{V} \approx \sqrt{8.41 + 321.565} \approx 18.165 $$

**Note:** $S$ is exactly the same as the sample standard deviation in the aggregated data set when you use the '$\frac{1}{n}$' sample variance rather than the unbiased sample variance (which scales by $\frac{1}{n-1}$). If you use the unbiased sample variance then $S$ slightly overestimates the standard deviation in the aggregated data set - I don't know which of these two standard deviations you've presented here.