# How to calculate the time 2 standard deviation given time 1 and change standard deviations?

Tags: standard-deviation

I need to calculate the mean(+/-SD) final value of a variable from the mean(+/-SD) baseline value and the mean(+/-SD) change from baseline. 
So, for example:

- Mean baseline weight is 40(+/-2) kg.
- Mean change from baseline is +5(+/-1) kg.

I'd assume the correct final mean is 45kg, but how would I go about calculating a new SD?

I've googled for methods of calculating 'Pooled SD', but those only seem to apply to pooling same variables (like weights from different groups) and I don't think those apply here.
[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21999/how-to-calculate-sd-from-pre-sd-and-post-sd) question seems the most similar to my question but also seems to try the exact opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should have the homework tag.

Comment: No, I want to recalculate missing data from articles, but that's only useful if I can also calculate a (reasonable) SD.

Comment: You cannot compute an SD without knowing the correlation between the two variables.

Comment: @whuber What do you mean by that?

Comment: The SD is the root of the variance. Let $X$ be the baseline weight and $Y$ the change from baseline. You need the variance of $X+Y$. It equals the variance of $X$ plus the variance of $Y$ *plus* twice the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. If there is nonzero correlation between $X$ and $Y$, that covariance will be nonzero and cannot be neglected.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your explanation. My question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible, as explained in Whuber's comment:

> The SD is the root of the variance. Let $X$ be the baseline weight and $Y$ the change from baseline. You need the variance of $X+Y$. It equals the variance of $X$ plus the variance of $Y$ *plus* twice the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. If there is nonzero correlation between $X$ and $Y$, that covariance will be nonzero and cannot be neglected.

Comment: Can you explain *why* this is the case? We want our answers to be a little more substantial than this (please see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which contains info about answering Q's among other topics). If you're just going to agree w/ @whuber's comment, this itself is best put as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I was just going to agree with Whuber's answer, but figured this would show the question as resolved.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't recognize that you were the OP.